# How to change focus on Web application?

Tags: web, bottle

I developed a Web application using Bottle. Unfortunately it behaviors not as I want. It has one text box and one 'submit' button.
Data is entered into text box using 1D scanner ( or just typing ) .. after that user should submit it.
The point is  that I don't want to click every  time on 'submit' button because it'll be a few hundreds of submission. Instead I want that after user scan/put data into text box he/she could just click on 'Return/Enter' key on keyboard. That way he/she will need only scan and click on Enter.
I tried but failed programmatically move focus from text box to 'submit' button but I tried my application on 2 machines. On one machine running Ubuntu and Firefox I don't have a problem i.e. after I enter data I just click on Enter button and it works. On another machine which I'm really interested to use application .. it runs Windows 7 and IE it does not work i.e. I have to enter data and then click on 'submit' button.
My question: could it be browser settings issue or something else that cause different behavior and how could I make it to work as I need i.e. enter data and just click 'Return'?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this with little bit of javascript :

```
$("form input").keypress(function (e) {
   if(e.which === 13) $("form").submit();
});
```

Comment: It didn't work for me. Could you please fix my code? I used this template and inserted your code.

Comment: <h2 style="text-align:center;">{{heading}}</h2>
<br>

<form action="/accession" method="GET">

      Barcode: <input id='barcode' type="text" size="1" name="barcode">

<input type="submit" name="save" onclick=e()  value="Save" $("form input").keypress(function (e) {
   if(e.which == 13) $("form").submit();
}) >

</form>

Comment: <p><b>Current Package:</b> {{curPkg}}

<p><b>List of the last 25 items received :</b></p>
<table border="2">

<th>pkg_id</th>
<th>vacutainer_id</th>

%for row in rows:
  <tr> 
  %for col in row:
    <td>{{col}}</td>
  %end
  </tr>
%end
</table>
</form>

<hr>
<br>

<!-- set focus -->
<script>
  document.getElementById('barcode').focus();
</script>
**
Alexander, thanks a lot for your help